# Start firefox using Another Profile, for specific file type(s)?

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, file-association, firefox-profile

I have two profiles. `A` and `B`
I have made shortcuts to start each profile as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p A
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p B
```

Also, I have set the profile B as default using `ProfileManager`

What I want to do is start another but the default profile, when I open a specific filetype.

The current association for the `.html` file is:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

and command line arguments as follows:

```
-requestPending -osint -url "%1"
```

This opens the specified url (from inside outlook for example) as the default firefox profile (`B` in my case). I want to open each `.html` extension using the `A` profile.

Mozilla, states that `-p` and `-requestPending -osint` cannot be used at the same time.

How do I open another profile for a specific filetype?

Comment: %appdata%/mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini lists profiles, `Default=1` is a line that marks a section like `[Profile0]` as a *default profile*. If in `[General]`, `StartWithLastProfile=1` is set, I think it starts the default profile. Now in theory you could write a wrapper batch file that in the first line executes a script, to be written, that sets the default profile in this ini and on the second line passes all arguments to firefox.exe. I would use [python](http://doc.pyschools.com/html/index.html)'s [ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser](http://pymotw.com/2/ConfigParser/) to write the lacked script.

Comment: Currently a solution to this question is here:

http://superuser.com/questions/767871/how-to-ensure-specific-firefox-profile-opens-html-extension-file#new-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way to do that is create forwarding rules in Browser Tamer: https://www.aloneguid.uk/projects/bt/

Comment: So after 11 years there is a good answer! Thanks Ivan

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a batch file. The following was tested and confirmed to work with Firefox 30.0.

**Associate .HTML Files With a Specific Firefox Profile**

Create a batch file with something like the following — for instance, for a web development profile called "Dev":

```
"C:\My Programs\FF30\firefox.exe" -P Dev -no-remote
```

You should omit any non-Firefox command line switches in the `.bat` file commands (i.e. do not put in `-osint -url "%1"`). If you have never create a batch file, simply open a text file, type the appropriate command(s) and save. Then rename the file extension from `.txt` to `.bat`.

Assuming your are using Windows XP, navigate to *My Computer* and select the *Tools -> Folder Options -> File Types* tab. You need to change this file type association:

- Firefox HTML Document

To be clear, to create a link only for actual `.html` files, just the first item needs to edited.  Select the *Advanced* button, then *Edit* the default "open" action. Under the field marked "Application used to perform action:" paste the path to your `.bat` file e.g.

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Desktop\Firefox.bat" "%1"
```

Make sure to use double quotes as above. Press *OK*, *OK* to finalize your changes.

You should, of course, copy the original entry in the field "just in case" and set it aside in case you want to reverse your changes at a later time. The basic form should be:

```
"C:\Path\To\Browser\firefox.exe" -osint -url "%1"
```